# Ubuntu 12.04 uWSGI fails to build

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, uwsgi

I have the following error when running:

```
python uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/php --verbose
using profile: buildconf/default.ini
detected include path: ['/usr/lib', '/var/lib', '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed', '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/include']
*** uWSGI building and linking plugin plugins/php ***
gcc -pthread -fPIC -shared -o ./php_plugin.so -I. -O2 -I. -Wall -Werror -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_MUTEX -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_EPOLL -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_TIMERFD -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_INOTIFY  -DUWSGI_PCRE -DUWSGI_ROUTING -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.3\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="3" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_SSL -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_LIBXML2 -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -Wno-sign-compare plugins/php/php_plugin.c -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcrypt -lz -lresolv -lcrypt -ldb -lbz2 -lz -lpcre -lrt -lm -ldl -lnsl -lxml2 -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -lssl -lcrypto -lxml2 -lssl -lcrypto -lxml2 -lxml2 -lcrypt -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lcrypt -lphp5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lphp5
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** unable to build php plugin ***
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

```
php -v
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 28 2014 23:14:25)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

On an overview level, it means link with the php5 library. If PHC is this: http://www.phpcompiler.org then it makes sense that it would be looking for the PHP lib. Where is this installed on your machine? You should be able to do: locate libphp5 and find it. If locate doesn't see it, you need to install PHP.

If php is already installed, (as you mentioned in the updated question, you will need to set the Linker path to point to that lib. There are a couple of ways for doing this, but the easiest would be to set it using

```
export D_LIBRARY_PATH=<path to the php lib>
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the php installation.

Comment: we figured out with the php plugin, now there's another error when running it: `./uwsgi -s :3031 --plugin php
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: libphp5-5.4.26-1~ppa1~precise.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!`. We installed `libphp5-embed` and `php5-dev` from http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/nathan-renniewaldock_ppa/precise/main/base/libphp5-embed